# PHP config quark with if statements

Tags: configuration, php

Ok this is weird on my development server if I am running a test on a script and shorthand a if statement like so:

```
if($_GET['cat']){ ...
```

Instead of a more pragmatic way like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){ ...
```

I will get errors stating that

> Notice: Undefined variable: pwdmsg in
>   C:\wamp\www\myfile\decrypt-text.php
>   on line 16

Just wondering if anyone would know what this could be not a big deal really because I only do it when I am testing a theory or trying to check something it is just an annoyance.

Oh and please don't ding my question if it's something totally stupid or like "...even n00bs know that!" I just know it doesn't do it on my live server but does on my dev server.

My basic dev-server info:

PHP 5.3.0
Apache 2.2.11
MySQL 5.1.36

PHP exts:
    * Core
    * bcmath
    * calendar
    * com_dotnet
    * ctype
    * date
    * ereg
    * filter
    * ftp
    * hash
    * iconv
    * json
    * mcrypt
    * mysqlnd
    * odbc
    * pcre
    * Reflection
    * session
    * SPL
    * standard
    * tokenizer
    * zip
    * zlib
    * libxml
    * dom
    * PDO
    * openssl
    * SimpleXML
    * wddx
    * xml
    * xmlreader
    * xmlwriter
    * apache2handler
    * curl
    * gd
    * imap
    * mbstring
    * mysql
    * mysqli
    * Phar
    * pdo_mysql
    * pdo_sqlite
    * mhash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say your error_reporting is configured differently.

http://de.php.net/manual/de/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

On dev-systems you often do

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

while on live-systems mostly E_ERROR is set to avoid output which is not user-relevant.

Comment: Oh man do I feel stupid, thanks so much. As soon as I seen E_ALL it snapped into place. thanks again.